# Sorting List of Objects by long property

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, comparator

It is possible to Compare int values using Collections.sort(object) like this:

```
Collections.sort(priceList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return Integer.parseInt(o1.getPrice()) - Integer.parseInt(o2.getPrice());
    }
});
```

and `Long.compare` is available in API 19 and higher to Compare long values using Collections.sort(object):

```
Collections.sort(priceList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return Long.compare(o2.getPrice(), o1.getPrice());
    }
});
```

but the `minSdkVersion` of my app is `16` and my price values are bigger than the maximum of int range!!!

How can I sort the List of my objects by `long` property in API level 16 and higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the definition of `Long#compare` :

```
public static int compare(long x, long y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Similary, you simply can `return 1` if the value greater than the other value, `0` if equals and `-1` if less than:

```
Collections.sort(priceList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
       return (o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) ? -1 : ((o1.getPrice() == o2.getPrice()) ? 0 :1 );
});
```

Comment: Oh my god. You're right. Tiredness didn't let me think well.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the compare method as follows. This should solve your problem.

```
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
                return o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice ?-1 :(o1.getPrice == o2.getPrice ?0 :1);

}
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct. Thank you for your time but Amit answered sooner.